# Net Core 3.1 access directories on another server

Tags: c#, .net-core-3.1

I am trying to create some code where I can navigate some directories on another server.

To do this I am trying to pass in the server name to `DirectoryInfo` class. Thus, my code is:

```
string serverPath = @"\someServer\c$\folder\folder\";

var serverDirectories = new DirectoryInfo (serverPath);
var directories= directories.GetDirectories();
```

The problem is when I try to get the directories it is not working, and I am seeing `c` in the path that I trying to get to. So, I tried using `Server.MapPath`, but this doesn't exist in .Net Core 3.1.

So, my question how do get a list of directory and files from another server in .Net Core 3.1?

Answer (score 0):

You need a double blackslash `\\` before the server name when accessing a remote server. Change your path to:

```
string serverPath = @"\\someServer\c$\folder\folder\";
```

A single blackslash references the root of your local filesystem, which is C:, so it looks for `C:\someServer\c$\folder\folder\ instead.

Comment: Still not working even with the extra \